# How to delete specific table row from backend and frontend?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an `Ajax.ActionLink` which sends a request to server and gets a result from server. So in `AjaxOption` I just write name of success function.

```
OnSuccess = "SuccessDeleteFunction"
```

but based on result I want to change DOM element.To pass current DOM element in success function I used this code:

```
OnSuccess = "SuccessDeleteFunction(this)"
```

But How can I have Both at the same time.

```
function SuccessDeleteFunction(result, tag) {

    if (result.Success) {
        //    do sth
    }
    eval(result.Script);
}
```

Here is my code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="ContentRow">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", "Product", new { id = @item.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { Confirm = "Are you sure?", HttpMethod = "get", OnSuccess = "SuccessDeleteFunction" }, new { @class = "btn fa fa-trash text-danger fa-2x " })

        </td>
     </tr>
}
```

Comment: you can't pass parameter to ajax success method. why you need it? it dose not make sense.

Comment: I want if the result is success then removes the parent tr. So there is no need to reload list from server and in clientt side i will handle it.

Comment: share you html also.

Comment: when you are making you html add an id to all tags TR which you want to remove and on success method select that TR (specific TR with the ID) and remove it. Share your html so i can help you in code.

Comment: good, Also add your TR's which is to be removed on this click.

Comment: Delete is by ajax call. If there is no problem in delete operation It will remove parent tr. else parent will not remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to your item `ID` to TR's like :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="ContentRow" id="tr_'@item.id'">
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
             </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
              </td>
               <td>
                 @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", "Product", new { id = @item.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { Confirm = "Are you sure?", HttpMethod = "get", OnSuccess = "SuccessDeleteFunction" }, new { @class = "btn fa fa-trash text-danger fa-2x " })

              </td>
        </tr>
   }
```

And in your `JS` code you have to do this, And one thing you need more is Return your item `ID` from `SERVER RESPONSE`

```
function SuccessDeleteFunction(result) {

    if (result.Success) {
        // also return your that id from server in response....
        $("tr_" + result.id).remove();
    }
    eval(result.Script);
}
```